# How Do I save Illustration as a Jpeg as it's normal size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, jpg

[image]

Hi there, I'm really struggling here

I am going to print these off in a little while as an A1

I set this up as a JPEG for me to print.

The left picture shows the way I want it to print out. The right picture shows the results I got from changing it to JPEG. The pictures are tiny and its just all white around it.

I went on to file, Export then changed it to JPEG. Then it turned out like that.

How do I get this to be the same size as before? On photoshop it seems really simple. But I'm just really stuck.

Please help. thanks

Comment: What is correct size?  Are you then asking why jpeg exports elements outside the artboard? Why on earth would you make it a jpg for print?

Comment: So, you have an AI file that contains an embedded jpg file, which you tried to export, but you were not able keep the original size when exporting? If that is the case, I'd have to ask why would you go from jpg to ai to jpg?

Answer (score 1):

When exporting, in the first pop-up,  under the format, check the option **"use artboards"**!

Hope it helped

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! And what is the result of using this option? Can you show an screenshot what you mean? An answer with only one line is a little bit too short, I think ...  Please explain better what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Although their answer is brief, this is the solution. It will export just the elements on the artboard and none outside of it. Similar in concept to cropping it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to increase the resolution of the exported jpg (Resolution: Other) until the image displays at the size you want. For a more exact formula, multiply the resolution by the image width in inches to predict the final image width on screen. Standard LCD resolution is 72ppi (pixels per inch) at 100%. So, for example, if you have a desired width of 1080, set your Illustrator art board to 14.8611 inches wide and export at 72ppi.
Note: You do not have to change your units of display in order to set your artboard in another unit. For example, if you are working in pixel units and you want to resize your artboard to 5 inches, simply change the width to "5in" (no space). When you include "in" for inches, "mm" for points, etc., Illustrator will convert it to the currently working unit.

Comment: This sounds unnecessarily complicated. All he/she needs to do is change the size of the artboard to that of the A1 format (594 x 841mm) and resize/arrange the elements of the illustration to fit that format.

Comment: The simpler the better.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer the root problem. If one designs with a certain format and certain dimensions in mind then that's the way it should be exported. Down-scaling your image after the fact to fit the paper format will give you the incorrect output. The simple solution is to do it correctly, not to cheat.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I've said. I've given instructions on how to export to the desired size in one motion. Also, I believe you're missing out on the awesome power of cheating. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @gburning In essence using computers is cheating, your underlying software do it all the time. Anyway the original question makes no sense.

Comment: No it does not. My "underlying software" is not compressing my work to a lossy format of smaller dimension only to scale it back up, resulting in not only worse quality than when I started out but with the wrong dimensions as well. It's the worse option and it is not simpler. Sorry if I'm being a jerk but it's simply not the right answer.

Comment: If the image information that is lost is so minor that it is undetectable to the eye, yet reduces the files size, there is only a benefit. If the information that is lost is detectable, then it was saved incorrectly for high quality printing. JPG compression is a tool. Like any tool, it can be misused. Whether one considers that to be cheating or not is irrelevant.

Comment: And I don't think you're being a jerk in any way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use JPEG. For one thing the JPEG format doesn't handle transparency which is why your background turns out white. It also compresses and rasterizes your images quite a bit which will cost you in quality when printing.
2. Do use PDF. PDF is the format most often used when sending a file to be printed as it's designed to be used for that. For one thing it supports vectorized graphics/images and for another it supports transparency. You can save PDF files by going to File > Save As and choose PDF in the dropdown menu at the bottom of the prompt.
3. As for the output being smaller in size than what it is on your screen: are you sure your artboard(s) are set to the right size (ie the A1 format) and that your artwork is contained in it? You can change the size of the artboard by using the Artboard Tool (Shift+O). Once that is correct you'll have to resize/rearrange your artwork to fit within that area.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer a question you are asking and some questions you are not asking but you need to know.

### Some objects out of the artboard size

Some objects like the trees are out of the artboard, but as they are part of the objects you have they are showing.

The huge white space to the right is probably used by some transparent objects or the nodes of this objects.

You can try to sellect everithing and put it inside a rectangle of the proportion you need.

I say proportion, not size, becouse if your original artboard is A4 or A3 it has the same proportion of an A1.

The exact steps depends on the aplication you are using, but you can use clipping mask in ilustrator or power clip in Corel Draw.

### Normal size

There is not "normal" size when exporting (not saving) into a raster file (Jpg, psd, tiff, etc.) The output size depends on the resolution you need to print it. Which is a totally diferent matter here, becouse depends on what is your source material, the printing method, final size and viewing distances. You just be carefull on that topic.

### Aditional methods to crop your exported file

You can export it as you are doing it right now and crop it after in a raster program. It is an option, but in your case the exported file is a lot bigger than you need it and your file will be too big.

You can "print" your image in a virtual printer. The information is send to a file, not an actual printer. You can shoose the "paper size" for example and the workflow will do the crop for you. The cons of this method is that you can probably loose some colour rpofiles in the process.

### Raster or no raster

Depending on the content of your file and the formats within you can send the output file as a raster one or leave it as vector if the case.

That decision depends on many things, out of the scope of the question. But they include original quality and format of the elements, color modes, effects aplied and format asked by the provider.

Answer (score -1):

So you're going about this the wrong way altogether.

**Your first problem is thinking that you need a jpg to print.**

If you are exporting an illustration as an image, you are losing quality anyway. The best thing to do is to **Save As** and then choose **Adobe PDF**.

If for some reason you **HAVE TO** have a jpg, then just do a **Save for Web** and you can choose your resolution in the output there. It seems counterintuitive, and it is, because jpgs in illustrator are only for web. PDF's and EPS are for printing.

Comment: There are many times when a high resolution raster format like JPG or TIFF is the best, most hassle-free way to ensure proper output. JPG's in illustrator are often intended for pring, btw. Combining raster and vector images in Illustrator is ubiquitous in the print industry, and it definitely has its place, depending on the desired result.

Comment: @13ruce, I'm going to have to disagree with you completely. JPG is one of the most lossy file types, and adds considerable artifacts to any vector created in illustrator. PDFs retain full raster and vector information better than any raster format.

Comment: That's a popular misconception. While it is entirely possible (and all too often a reality) to make a terribly poor quality JPG, I submit that a properly created JPG is indistinguishable from the highest quality TIFF. Compression artifacts are only visible when the algorithm is allowed to create them.

Comment: Resaving a JPG over and over will also eventually result in a poor quality image. However, we're not talking about abusing the format. We're talking about using it properly. Open any magazine to an advertisement. The image you see was probably a JPG before it was a TIFF. In fact all of the major high-end stock art sites supply images chiefly in JPG and EPS formats.

Comment: Considering that in the past year I've created over 200 print ads for nationally distributed magazines, I would have to tell you that only once have I ever been asked to submit a final file as a TIFF and never a JPG. The only way to get a lossless jpg is to sacrifice file size, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: A lossless JPG is completely unnecessary in order to create an image that the human eye cannot distinguish from perfect. You're right in that no vendor requires JPGs as print-ready art, nor was that what I was suggesting. Yet, JPGs are indeed used by the millions by print designers every day as the links used to build print-ready art. Incidentally, by default, employs JPG compression. It is certainly your right to avoid them, but it is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: The bottom line is that visible compression artifacts are the result of poor design, and are in no way a necessity of the image format itself. Therefore it would be more helpful, in my opinion, to advise proper use of the tool rather than avoiding it altogether out of unnecessary, ill-informed reticence.

Comment: I agree with 13ruce comments. **Jpg Is a viable option when you need that option.** - About the compression. If you know how to handle a jpg you only losse less than 0.5% information. That is way less than the human eye can see on screen and a printed format. Here are some compression tests. They are in spanish but you can see the process and the results: http://otake.com.mx/Apuntes/PruebasDeCompresion2/2-CompresionJpgCalidad.htm